# Universal elimination in Fitch

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I've returned to tinkering with some arguments in Fitch after not having had anything to do with formal logic in a while, and I suppose I've grown rustier than I thought I had because I simply can't figure out why the following application of universal elimination is invalid.

[image]

For reference, here is the correction application of the rule:

[image]

I suppose I was expecting that all instances of the quantified variable would be replaced with the arbitrary variable. Why is this not the case? Why does Px not become Pa?

Comment: The correction is wrong and you're right.

Comment: @user21820 found the fix. The software requires that you use brackets between the predicate-symbol and the variable. So, that statement would be "∀x∀y ((P(x) ∧ ¬P(y))  → ( y < x) )"

Comment: My guess is that the system you are using may be parsing "Px" as a propositional-symbol, whereas you want it to understand "P(x)" as a predicate-symbol applied to "x".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I simply can't figure out why the following application of universal elimination is invalid. $$\begin{array}{|l}\forall x~\forall y~((Px\land\lnot Py)\to(y<x))\\\hline\begin{array}{|l}\boxed a\\\hline\forall y~((Pa\land\lnot Py)\to(y<a))\end{array}\end{array}$$

$\bullet$ That is because it *is* valid.   You have instantiated all free occurrences of the predicate's bound variable ($x$) to the assumed variable ($a$).

> For reference, here is the correction application of the rule:
>
> $$\begin{array}{|l}\forall x~\forall y~((Px\land\lnot Py)\to(y<x))\\\hline\begin{array}{|l}\boxed a\\\hline\forall y~((Px\land\lnot Py)\to(y<a))\end{array}\end{array}$$

$\color{red}{\large\times}$ This correction is incorrect; it is in fact an *invalid* inference.   This leaves an occurrence of the bound variable free.   It should be disallowed by your proof checker.   Submit an error ticket to the developers.